# Upgrading kernel by dist-upgrade

Tags: kernel

I upgraded kernel version by `dist-upgrade`. The version I upgraded to was 4.4.0-78. but after rebooting when I typed `sudo uname -r`, it showed 4.4.0-34.  What's wrong? There were no problems while upgrading.

I use Ubuntu amd64  16.04

Comment: Is the system installed on a VPS?

Comment: what is the output of `dpkg -l linux-image-4* | grep ^ii` ?

Comment: @Pilot6 you mean virtualbox or smth?

Comment: @Ravexina here you go:  ii  linux-image-4.4.0-34-generic 4.4.0-34.53  amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-72-generic 4.4.0-72.93  amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-78-generic 4.4.0-78.99  amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-79-generic 4.4.0-79.100 amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP

Comment: Run `sudo grub-install /dev/sda` then `sudo update-grub`. (change sda whit your desired hard drive if there is any). reboot the system and let me know that happens.

Comment: you mean where Ubuntu is installed by desired hdd?

Comment: Ubuntu is installed in /dev/sdb2

Comment: `sudo grub-install /dev/sdb` and `sudo update-grub`. reboot the system. You should use "@username" to mention who you are talking with otherwise they won't be notified about your comment.

Comment: @Ravexina `sudo grub-install /dev/sdb` showed `/dev/sdb does not have any corresponding BIOS drive` I tried other sda sdb, but all the same error